# QTextCursor::clearSelection() doesn't clear my selection

Tags: c++, qt

[image: Each line is center]

```
    ui->textEdit->setText(qry.value(2).toString());
    ui->textEdit->selectAll();
    QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();

    QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
    textBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);

    cursor.clearSelection();
```

I try to clear the selection but does nothing.

```
cursor.clearSelection();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ui->textEdit->setText(qry.value(2).toString());
    // ui->textEdit->selectAll();
    QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
    cursor.select( QTextCursor::Document );

    QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
    textBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);
    cursor.movePosition( QTextCursor::Start );
    ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
    cursor.clearSelection();
```